# How to represent an array of arrays in a relational database

Tags: django, database, database-design, relational-database

I need to design a database schema for the following problem. Consider this simplified grammatical 'analysis' of some example phrase:

- 'Extraordinarily incompetent taxi-driver'

  1. Extra-₁  ordinari₂  -ly₃
  2. in-₁  competent₂
  3. taxi-₁  driv₂  -er₃

In this model a *sentence* consists of an array of words, and a *word* is made up of an array of *word parts/morphemes*. Relational databases are – as I am learning, notoriously – not very happy about arrays of arrays.

I see two solutions and am unsure how to make the right decision. The **first, 'dirty' solution**: a single intermediary table which links sentences with morphemes, and stores the array indices. Lots of identical entries in columns.

```
CREATE TABLE word (           -- pseudo-SQL
  sentence_id FOREIGN KEY,
  sentence_order INTEGER,
  morpheme_id FOREIGN KEY,
  morpheme_order INTEGER );
```

The **second, 'clean' solution**: Three (!) intermediary tables, probably slow and uncomfortable to use? Note how the *word* table only serves up IDs for the two foreign key tables to use.

```
CREATE TABLE sentence_word (
  sentence_id FOREIGN KEY,
  word_id FOREIGN KEY,
  order INTEGER );
CREATE TABLE word ( id );
CREATE TABLE morpheme_word (
  morpheme_id INTEGER FOREIGN KEY,
  word_id INTEGER FOREIGN KEY
  order INTEGER );
```

I would normally prefer a clean solution but here the clean solution has a kludgy feel to it. I'm trying to do this with a web framework ORM, by the way (Django).

Comment: To be honest, my 2cts is that relational database is a poor starting point to anything with NLP (Natural Language Processing). Otherwise your second design makes sense (somehow).

Comment: Some relational databases (e.g. Oracle) have the concept of nested table (http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/NESTED_TABLE), which can be used to implement array of arrays.

Comment: Yes, some databases support array types; MongoDB allows similar stuff. But given the framework I am working with I'm looking for a more low-tech/truly relational solution (MySQL or PostgreSQL will do).

Answer (score 2):

Your second solution is the technically correct one.  The kludge you're feeling is in fact not due to the array of arrays problem but to the fact that you have a many to many relationship between sentence and word, and between morpheme and word.  (Any given sentence could be one or many words, and any word could be part of one or many sentences.)  This is a normal kludge that is an (unfortunate?) side effect of SQL.

Since you mention django, django attempts to abstract some of this for you with [many-to-many fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#many-to-many-relationships).

I think as a basic model for your django you're looking at something like this:

```py
class Sentence(models.Model):
    words = models.ManyToManyField(Words, through=SentenceWord)

class Word(models.Model):
    morphenes = models.ManyToManyField(Morphene, through=MorpheneWord)

class Mophene(models.Model):
    pass


#--- Intermediate Tables ------------
class SentenceWord(models.Model):
    sentence = models.ForeignKey(Sentence)
    word = models.ForeignKey(Word)
    position = models.IntegerField()

class MorpheneWord(models.Model):
    word = models.ForeignKey(Word)
    morphene = models.ForeignKey(Morphene)
    position = models.IntegerField()
```

Admittedly, I just typed up those models here, but that should get you close to where to need to be.

*EDIT:* Introduced Word Model.

Comment: Your Django model seems a bit different than both OP's 1st and 2nd model. Your model does not have a `Word` relation.

Comment: For a first design, going without a _word_ relation would actually work in my case. Thanks! But I'm also thinking ahead: as soon as the 'word' concept would get fleshed out a bit it would certainly need its own table.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have a hard time enforcing proper morpheme order in the first design, and for that reason I *like* the second design better. However, if performance is the issue, the first design might allow you to do less JOINing.

If you happen to use Oracle, you might be able to have your cake an eat it too, by marrying the second design for "cleanliness" with [materialized views](http://chinmi.wordpress.com/2008/04/29/materialized-views-in-oracle-8158i9i10g11g-4/) for performance.

Comment: The other disadvantage of the 1st design is that you can't store a word without storing a sentence that it belongs too.

Answer (score 0):

If we take the data structure involved as an array of array *values*, there is a simple alternative solution that is **clean**, **efficient**, and **intuitive to work with**:

```
CREATE TABLE Sentence (...);
CREATE TABLE Word     ( sentence_id FOREIGN KEY,
                        order INTEGER );
CREATE TABLE Morpheme ( word_id FOREIGN KEY,
                        order INTEGER );
```

This is simply a 1-to-N relationship, twice. (With Django's ORM you could then simply say `word.sentence` to access the sentence a Word instance belongs to, or `sentence.word_set.order_by('order')` to get the ordered set of words in some sentence.)

The **drawback** of this design is that array items which occur many times, such as *-ly* in *extraordinari-ly*, are stored many times in the database, once for each occurrence. It is not possible to associate additional data with all *-ly* morphemes.